# Multiple fields but only extract the first key's value?

Tags: key, jq

The title could've been done better, but sometimes my english vocabulary is as lacking as my JSON skills (despite jqplay.org being a useful resource) :(

Anywho; I'm trying to extract the first **username** value under the `"accounts"` field. The problem is, there are multiple entries ("someone" and "someoneelse") and i only need the first key's value in the list ("JQ_Newb" or "GOD", depending on how the JSON is parsed).

**The JSON's contents are as followed:**

```
{
  "accounts": {
    "someone": {
      "username": "JQ_Newb",
      "info": "stackoverflow"
    },
    "someoneelse": {
      "username": "GOD",
      "info": "heaven"
    }
  }
}
```

I've been fiddling around with `to_entries[]` and `select()` (with and without values between [] and () ), but all that i'm getting is:

```
{
  "key": "extra",
  "value": "stackoverflow"
}
{
  "key": "extra",
  "value": "heaven"
}
```

and:

```
"JQ_Newb"
"GOD"
```

using `.accounts[].username`

**TL;DR**

```
.accounts[]|to_entries[0]|select(i_dont_know_what_i'm_doing)
```

If a solution is already on Stackoverflow, i'm sorry i couldn't find it.
I've tried my best to solve this problem, myself.

Thanks,

**copyitright**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your jq has `first/1`:

```
first(.accounts[] | .username)
```

Otherwise you might like to consider:

```
[.accounts[] | .username][0]
```

Comment: How can things that look so simple, be so hard to find!? Greatly appreciated, peak! (the first solution works with jq-win32 1.5) :-)